# How to distribute source of a Qt project?

Tags: qt, qt-creator, autotools, qmake

I created a program using Qt Creator and want to pass it to somebody. Due to the lack of an elegant solution I wrote a script that packs all relevant files and tell the person to unpack and execute `qmake -makefile`.

Is there a standard way to do this? Or even an autotools-way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually you tar/zip everything together, or if you use a VCS (which you should), create a tag and export the source and .pro files (git archive, svn export, etc.). Or give the other person access to the VCS.

Of course you can also use other build systems than QMake with Qt. To minimize pain, I wouldn't suggest autotools though, but cmake. (That also works well on Windows, if you target that).